# Maximum and minimum values of intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know how to do this problem, but my question is more on the proving the inequality and the extreme values.

So here is the problem:

Of the 24 students in a class, 18 like to play basketball and 12 like to play volleyball. It is given that
$\epsilon=\{\text{students in the class}\}$
$B=\{\text{students who like to play basketball}\}$ and
$V=\{\text{students who like to play volleyball}\}$.
Find the smallest possible value of $n(B\cap V)$ and the largest possible value of $n(B\cap V)$.

Answer:
$n(B\cap V)$ is smallest when $B\cup V=\epsilon$, so $n(B\cap V)=6$. and $n(B\cap V)$ is largest when $V\subset B$, so $n(B\cap V)=12$.

It makes sense and I know how to do this problem, my question is not how to get 6 and 12, but how to prove that:
1. $n(B\cap V)$ is smallest when $B\cup V=\epsilon$
2. $n(B\cap V)$ is largest when $V\subset B$

I can use the common sense to explain those facts, but is there any formula or inequality that we can use to prove them? Thanks.

Comment: The following formula may be familiar, and is quite useful: $n(X\cup Y)=n(X)+n(Y)-n(X\cap Y)$. It will take care of (1).

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Thanks, I know the inclusion-exclusion principle, but why is it the smallest?

Comment: Given $n(X)$ and $n(Y)$, by the formula, the number $n(X\cap Y)$ is smallest when $n(X\cup Y)$ is biggest. and you can't get bigger than the universe.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. You're right. Thanks! That will also prove (2), $n(X\cup Y)$ is smallest when either $X$ or $Y$ is included in the other depending which one is larger.

Comment: @user71346,precisely.To help visualize the problem,you can also use Venn diagrams,although they are not necessary.